# What is the purpose of the [1] in this list in a list?

Tags: python

I'm self-learning Python and ran into a problem I'm having difficulty with.

I'm working with Paul Barry's Headfirst Python.

The list is as follows:

```py
movies = [
    "The Holy Grail",
    1975,
    "Terry Jones & Terry Gilliam",
    91,
    [
        "Graham Chapman",
        [
            "Michael Palin",
            "John Cleese",
            "Terry Gilliam",
            "Eric Idle",
            "Terry Jones",
        ],
    ],
]
```

The code is

```py
print(movies[4][1][3])
```

to generate `Eric Idle`. Yet, I'm unsure what the purpose of the `[1]` is here, and how the count generated the response.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Let's restructure the definition a little, adding comments on the right indicating the indexes:

```
movies = [
    "The Holy Grail",                   # [0]
    1975,                               # [1]
    "Terry Jones & Terry Gilliam",      # [2]
    91,                                 # [3]
    [                                   # [4]-begin
        "Graham Chapman",               # [4][0]
        [                               # [4][1]-begin
            "Michael Palin",            # [4][1][0]
            "John Cleese",              # [4][1][1]
            "Terry Gilliam",            # [4][1][2]
            "Eric Idle",                # [4][1][3]
            "Terry Jones"               # [4][1][4]
        ]                               # [4][1]-end
    ]                                   # [4]-end
]
```

`movies[4]` is a list. `movies[4][0]` is "Graham Chapman", and `movies[4][1]` is another list, which has "Eric Idle" at index 3.

Answer (score 2):

Since it a nested list, Indexing comes in handy:

> Indexing starts from 0, and not 1.

```
movies = ["The Holy Grail", 1975, "Terry Jones & Terry Gilliam", 91, ["Graham Chapman", ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]]]
```

**Elaborated**:

```
print(movies[4])
```

Would give you the `4th` element which is a nested `list`

```
print(movies[4][1])
```

Would give you the `1st` element of that nested list `movies[4]`, which is a `list`

```
print(movies[4][1][3])
```

Would give you the `3rd` element of that list `movies[4][1]`, which is a `str`

**Hence**:

```
print(movies[4])   # ["Graham Chapman", ["Michael Palin", "John Cleese", "Terry Gilliam", "Eric Idle", "Terry Jones"]]

print(movies[4][1])   # ['Michael Palin', 'John Cleese', 'Terry Gilliam', 'Eric Idle', 'Terry Jones']

print(movies[4][1][3])   # Eric Idle
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly include the (non-)word "zeroth" somewhere, people are probably going to assume normal English definition of "first" et al, "first" being index 0.